# $\|f\|_4 \le C \|f\|_2$ for all $f \in L^4([0,1])$

Tags: measure-theory

Does there exist a constant $C$ such that $\|f\|_4 \le C \|f\|_2$ forall $f  \in L^4([0,1])$?

I haven't been able to find this $C$, so I'm not sure if it exists or not.

Comment: No, but there *does* exist a constant such that $\|f\|_2\le C\|f\|_4$ (Hölder's inequality).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take $f(x)=x^n$ then $\|f\|_4 = \left(\frac{1}{4n+1}\right)^{1/4}$ and $\|f\|_2 = \left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)^{1/2}$.

Therefore if such constant exists it follows that
$$ \frac{1}{4n+1} \leq C^4 \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$$ which is false for $n$ great enough.